# Integral that is not defined at upper bound

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{1}{x \sqrt{(1-x)x}} dx$$

I would compute this as

$$ \frac{2(x-1)}{\sqrt{(1-x)x}}\biggr\rvert_{1/2}^1 $$

which is not defined at $1$.

However, Mathematica evaluates the definite integrals as $2$.

I can see how one would obtain approximately 2 by evaluating it close to 1, but is it correct?

In other words: Is $2$ the correct answer, or is the integral really not defined?

Comment: Consider $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac {2(x-1)}{\sqrt{(1-x)(x)}}$,  Does the limit exist?  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an *improper integral* and should indeed be interpreted as
$$
\lim_{t\to1}\int_{1/2}^t\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx
$$
You have correctly computed the antiderivative, so you get
$$
\lim_{t\to 1}-\frac{2(1-x)}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,\bigg|_{1/2}^t=
\lim_{t\to 1}\left(-\frac{2(1-t)}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/4}}\right)
$$
However,
$$
-\frac{2(1-t)}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}=-\frac{2\sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
so the limit is indeed $2$.

Comment: aren't you missing a $\sqrt{}$ in the last denominator?

Comment: @user159517 Yes, of course you're right.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2(x-1)}{\sqrt{(1-x)x}} = -\frac{2(\sqrt{1-x})^2}{\sqrt{(1-x)x}} = -2\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}$$

which should be easy to evaluate at $x=1$.